# Convert an SVG path that crosses itself to closed path

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs, openseadragon

I am using a library to allow my user to draw on canvas like a marker ([fabric.js](http://altert.github.io/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay/demo.html)), after the user draws, I check for intersections with the area he drew and other objects.

It works when the user draws a closed path, but since it's like a marker draw, the user can create a path that crosses itself, which creates a path with holes.

I am trying to figure out how to create a simple path that represents the area the user marked.

My Idea: Converting the canvas to png and creating a path based on the marked area but I couldn't find any information on how to do that.

Any other ideas or maybe something that could help me with my idea?

Comment: Why not listen to the mouse drag event on the canvas the user is drawing on and construct a path as the user drag mouse around. Add the newly constructed path to an array when the user releases the mouse after drag, repeat this process to construct all the path. Now you have paths to calculate for your intercept etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fill rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule) `"nonzero"` to fill the holes created by an overlapping path.